# how to convert from MySQL timestamp to PHP Y-m-d?

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have next code:

```
//$item['Update']="2015-02-16 16:03:13"; value from debug,from mysql
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item['Update']));
```

Why is it return 1970-01-01 ?

***Problem is resolved,data from mysql was empty.***

Comment: it returns `2015-02-16` for me.

Comment: [Can't reproduce it.](http://3v4l.org/H6kLh)

Comment: Add an `echo` before `date()` else it returns nothing.

Comment: Its working for me. I added echo before date().

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: Are you sure that your database has proper value? Because if its not then it will give 1970-01-01.

Comment: echo $item['Update']; It might not return date

Comment: @Daan make sure that your database field has proper value?

Comment: @Hakim   PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes yes
[screen from debug]:http://joxi.ru/5mdNNBgfo5w5A1

Comment: Is it possible to check whole code personally? Email: mijo.jfwg@gmail.com. I am pretty much interested on what u r doing.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes sorry, but it is not possible.

Comment: Your problem resolved?

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes, yes, problem was insignificant.

Comment: You wrote that you mysql field was empty. I was asking for that to check from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item['Update']));
```

Also check this out (to do it in MySQL way.)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Updated:

```
$item['Update'] = '2015-02-16 16:03:13';
$date = new DateTime($item['Update']);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2015-02-16
```

Output for Both statements:

```
Date is 2015-02-16
```

Comment: Jan 1 1970 2:00 AM - result, but i need 2015-02-16

Answer (score 0):

Use this with single quotes rather than double quotes

```
$item['Update']='2015-02-16 16:03:13'; 
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item['Update']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not really converting the format of the date and just stripping the time off it would be more efficient to use `substr`

```
<?php
    $item['Update']="2015-02-16 16:03:13";
    echo substr($item['Update'],0,10);
?>
```